# Removing duplicates CollectionUtils.collate method

Tags: java, apache-commons-collection

I'm trying to find the union of two collections by using the CollectionUtils.collate method. This method comes from the package *org.apache.commons.collections4*

Here is the code portion :

```
Collection<String> tokensUnion2 = CollectionUtils.collate(
    Arrays.asList(new String[]{"my", "sentence", "test", "for", "testing"}), 
    Arrays.asList(new String[]{"my", "sentence", "test", "is", "this"}), 
    false);
```

The result collection is the one below :

```
[my, sentence, test, for, test, is, testing, this]
```

As you can see, the resulting collection contains duplicates, even though the third parameter of *CollectionUtils.collate* indicates that I don't want duplicates.

Plus, the String duplicate *sentence* was eliminated, but the *test* is still there.

I could resolve this issue by simply putting the resulting collection in a *HashSet*, but I'd like to know what I've done wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collate method expects two sorted collections. The java doc for CollectionUtils#collate says: *Merges two sorted Collections, a and b, into a single, sorted List such that the natural ordering of the elements is retained.*

In your example, the two Lists supplied as arguments are not sorted. If you modify the code to sort the List like

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "my", "sentence", "test", "for", "testing" });
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "my", "sentence", "test", "is", "this" });

Collections.sort(list1);
Collections.sort(list2);

Collection<String> tokensUnion2 = CollectionUtils.collate(list1, list2, false);
```

This will return you a sorted Collection which will have no duplicates

```
[for, is, my, sentence, test, testing, this]
```

I hope this helps.